How do I "not in" to drop rows in a dataframe?
I'm trying to read the "Results by State" table into usable dataframes for me for:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_United_States_presidential_election#Results_by_state
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_United_States_presidential_election#Results_by_state
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_United_States_presidential_election#Results_by_state
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_United_States_presidential_election#Results_by_state
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_United_States_presidential_election#Results_by_state
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_United_States_presidential_election#Results_by_state
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1996_United_States_presidential_election#Results_by_state
Some, but not all of these tables have a totals row near the bottom, that I want to delete. I was hoping to do something like:
table = table['total' not in table['State or District'].lower()]

But have had no success. The following works, but hardly seems elegant.
table = table[table['State or District'] != 'USTotal']
table = table[table['State or District'] != 'Totals']
table = table[table['State or District'] != 'TOTALS']
table = table[table['State or District'] != 'Total']

My question was tagged for being a duplicate of
How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL
Indeed, the following works, but still isn't as elegant as what I would expect could be done.
table = table[~table['State or District'].isin(['USTotal','Totals','TOTALS','Total'])]

Late in his post, @cs95 provides a solution that has the same flavor that I want. The following code leans on this suggestion and works. Still, I have the sense (want to believe) the code could be more concise.
table = table[['total' not in x.lower() for x in table['State or District']]]


show us your code, even though it's not working
